# Ubuntu 18.04 reboots every 4 weeks

Tags: syslog, upgrade, ubuntu-18.04, reboot

Can anyone explain why my Ubuntu 18.04 server has rebooted every 28 days for last few months? I do not have `unattended-upgrades` configured to do so. I do have Canonical LivePatch, but this seems like the opposite of the behavior that that should cause. I've checked `syslog` around the time of the reboots and don't see anything untoward.

Comment: Is it a physical server, or VM?  Is it in the cloud or something?  If it isn't on physical hardware, is it something initiated by the hypervisor/cloud/etc?

Comment: Are there any cronjobs or other scheduled tasks that might be happening around that time, that might be crashing or something?

Comment: I once had a server like that. Turned out it was "protected" by an APC UPS that does a battery selftest every 4 weeks, and the batteries were completely worn out... The monitoring cable and/or software weren't installed so the battery problem couldn't be reported.

Comment: It's a physical server @Zoredache. I haven't identified any such cron jobs; and it hasn't occurred at the exact same time on those days.

Comment: @wurtel I've also had that previously, where reboots would occur every 2 weeks with my current UPS. However, that would cause multiple attached servers to restart, but this is contained to one.